# Program not showing returned values

Tags: python, recursion

I saw the code in an answer here, and I'm trying to pick it apart to see how it works. I think I understand it (using the or operator as a sort of ersatz "if" statement.), but that's not the  issue here. It is supposed to return a value, and after visualizing the code([done here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)) it apparently IS returning a value. However, when I run it in the terminal, no values are ACTUALLY displayed. What is happening?

```
def ispalin(word):
    return(not word) or (word[0]==word[-1] and ispalin(word[1:-1]))
ispalin(input("Enter a word."))
```

When this runs, it asks for a value, but nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 4):

That is because you are just `return`ing the value and not printing it

```
print (ispalin(input("Enter a word.")))
```

Will print out your values

O/P after changing the sentence

```
Enter a word.malayalam
True
```

Comment: do not change return to print! the return value is used in recursion and not returning will cause problems.

Comment: @acushner Oh yeah. I forgot that. Thanks for helpin before I got downvotes

Comment: I didn't change return to print for that reason. Thanks for the solution! 

I feel stupid..

Comment: @user3419886 You are welcome, Do accept the answer if you think it has answered your question

Answer (score 4):

Unless you run code in the interpreter, Python will not just print return values in module-level code.

You need to *explicitly* print your result:

```
print(ispalin(input("Enter a word.")))
```

The interactive interpreter session is a [REPL, or *Read-Eval-Print loop*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), where it'll print the results of whatever you try, but when you run code from the command line or when doubleclicking on your script, no printing takes place.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
print ispalin(input("Enter a word."))
```